# Any language where every class instance is a class too?

Tags: programming-languages, object-oriented, class

Taking inspiration from Javascript prototypes, I had the idea of a language where every instance can be used as a class.

Before I potentially reinvent the wheel, I would like to ask if there is a language already using this concept:

```
//To declare a Class, extend the base class (in this case, Type)
Type(Weapon,{price:0});

//Same syntax to inherit; simply extend the parent:
Weapon(Sword,{price:3});
Weapon(Axe,{price:4});

Sword(Katana,{price:7});
Sword(Dagger,{price:3});

//And the same to create an instance:
Katana(myKatana,{nickname:"Leon"});
myKatana.price; // 7
myKatana.nickname; // Leon

// An operator to return children of a class;
Sword_; // [Katana, Dagger]

// An operator to return array of descendants;
Sword__; // [Katana, Dagger, myKatana]

// An operator to return array of parents;
Sword^; // Weapon

// Arrays can be used as elements
Sword__.price += 1; //increases price of Sword's descendants by 1
mySword.price; //8

// And to access specific element (using its name instead of index)
var name = "mySword"
Katana_[name]; // [mySword]
Katana_[name].nickname; // Leon
```

Has this kind of approach been already studied/implemented?

Comment: Yes. See the following Wikipedia article on the concept: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming

Answer (score 5):

JavaScript can already do this without the syntax sugar.

[Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/53A7b/9/)

Note the syntax is significantly uglier. It should be possible to write a DSL on top of JavaScript that uses your syntax

```
//To declare a Class, extend the base class (in this case, Type)
var Weapon = create(Object.prototype, { 
    price: 0,
    name: "Weapon"
})

//Same syntax to inherit; simply extend the parent:
var Sword = create(Weapon, { 
    price: 3,
    name: "Sword"
})
var Axe = create(Weapon, { 
    price: 4,
    name: "Axe"
})

var Katana = create(Sword, { 
    price: 7,
    name: "Katana"
})
var Dagger = create(Sword, { 
    price: 3,
    name: "Dagger"
})

//And the same to create an instance:
var myKatana = create(Katana, { 
    nickname: "Leon",
    name: "myKatana"
})
console.log(myKatana.price) // 7
console.log(myKatana.nickname) // Leon

// An operator to return children of a class;
console.log(children(Sword)) // [Katana, Dagger]

// An operator to return array of descendants;
console.log(descendants(Sword)) // [Katana, Dagger, myKatana]

// An operator to return array of parents;
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Sword)); // Weapon

// Arrays can be used as elements
descendants(Sword).forEach(function (proto) {
    if (proto.hasOwnProperty("price")) proto.price += 1
})
console.log(myKatana.price) //8

// And to access specific element (using its name instead of index)
var name = "myKatana"
console.log(children(Katana)[name]) // [mySword]
console.log(children(Katana)[name].nickname) // Leon

function create(proto, props) {
    Object.keys(props).forEach(function (key) {
        props[key] = { 
            value: props[key],
            writable: true,
            configurable: true,
            enumerable: true
        }
    })
    var instance = Object.create(proto, props)
    if (!proto.hasOwnProperty("__children__")) {
        proto.__children__ = []
    }
    proto.__children__.push(instance)
    proto.__children__[props.name.value] = instance
    return instance
}

function children(proto) {
    return proto.__children__
}

function descendants(proto) {
    return proto.__children__.reduce(function (memo, value) {
        memo.push(value)
        if (value.hasOwnProperty("__children__")) {
            memo = memo.concat(descendants(value))
        }
        return memo
    }, [])
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I haven't seen a language exactly like yours, but prototype inheritance exists in JavaScript, for example.  Which seems to me to satisfy your "every class instance is a class too".  Unless your requirements are more specific than that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure it's an exact match for your description, but based on your examples this seems fairly close to the [io](http://iolanguage.com/) language.

More specifically, since you always create new "subclasses" in io by cloning an existing object, you're always able to treat any "subclass" as a distinct type upon which to base instances.

For some additional, hopefully clarifying, information, this section of the docs is probably the most relevant:

http://www.iolanguage.com/scm/io/docs/IoGuide.html#Objects-Inheritance